# Symfony - Ajax and Twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I am working on Symfony2 project. And now want to add some dynamic actions.
I want to use jQuery and Ajax calls and API.

Below I wrote my project model.
[image: my model]

Issue is there where I put "?" on the picture.

For example I have comments in my page and 2 buttons "oldest" "newest".

Basically on the page load TWIG load comment to my view and everything works fine.
Then I want to click on the button to change way of display comments. But want to do this without reloading a page.
I click btn -> run JavaScript -> connect byt AJAX with API controller -> take back data from database ... And here I stuck

I have data in JSON but have no idea how to load them into my view instead a date loaded by Twig at the beginning.

That's a serious wall on my way to dynamic changes on web page.
Thinking about:

- Creating all the view in JavaScript and replace twig data on the view using jQuery like .html() or something - but there would be a lot of HTML code in JavaScript script, not sure that's right way

Maybe you know how to solve that issue in more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Twig, but a JQuery concern. Here is an example.

Route:

```
my_symfony_route:
    path:     /get-filtered-list
    defaults: { _controller: "CompanyMyBundle:Comment:getFilteredList" }
    methods:  POST
```

Controller

```
public function getFilteredListAction(Request $request)
{
    $param1= $request->request->get('param1');
    $param2= $request->request->get('param2');

    $result = array();
    //Fill $result with DB request

    return new JsonResponse($result);  
}
```

JQuery request

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: "{{ path('my_symfony_route') }}",
    data: { param1: 'value', param2: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        //Handle your JSON data to update the DOM
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $('#myDivId').append($('<div>', {
                text: element.name
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: sdespont:  thank you for answer, now I think I will handle it. One more question. If I have to create a lot of HTML code in response, where should I keep this code? In JS scrpit? Dont want to make mess in my project and want to fallow web standards. Thank you

Comment: @RadekS I would put the html fragment in a JS function called in the AJAX callback. Or better, using JQuery `load` function. That way, the load function call a standard URL which render your fragment as you want and put it into a div. https://api.jquery.com/load/